# How to disable reactive form property in angular 2

Tags: angular2-forms, disabled-control, reactive

I have one reactive form and i take one array inside form my implementation is like

```
testForm:FormGroup;

fb is instance of FormBuilder;

this.testForm=this.fb.group({

testarray:this.fb.Array([
note:['']
])
})
```

I am using above array on my html to display note. Here functionality is like user can add multiple note.

I want to disable and enable note of array when i post not at that time want to identify which not is posted and need to disable that note.

Here my question is how can we disable reactive form array property using angular 2 typescript?

Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For starters this:

```
testarray:this.fb.Array([
  note:['']
])
```

is not valid syntax, you're trying to assign a `note` property to an array. I think what you want is this (also notice the lowercase a in array):

```
testarray: this.fb.array([
  this.fb.control('')
])
```

Then when you want to disable a control in the array you can simply call `.disable()`on it.

So let's say you have a control:

```
const myControl = this.testForm.get('testarray').controls[0];
```

You would do

```
myControl.disable();
```